# How to crop json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have json

```json
{......."tetx", "N_PHONE": ["8 (123) 456 67 89"], "ID_RENDER": .......}
```

```sql
SELECT t1.data ->>'N_PHONE' FROM db.t1
```

And we get

```json
["8 (123) 456 67 89"]
```

I want to get the text to load into another table, without quotes and brackets `8 (123) 456 67 89`

substring not suitable, there may be several numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the array element as text:

```
SELECT t1.data -> 'N_PHONE' ->> 0 
FROM db.t1
```

or using the `#>>` operator

```
SELECT t1.data #>> {N_PHONE, 0}
FROM db.t1
```

Comment: -> 'N_PHONE' ->> 0  this method works,
Thank you wery match